# luatex code for checking/avoiding hyphen at page break

Tags: luatex, page-breaking, hyphenation

There are cool things made possible by Lua, e.g. [Paragraph callback to help with widows/orphans hand tuning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372062/paragraph-callback-to-help-with-widows-orphans-hand-tuning) .

In the final version, I often do "by hand" checking that last line before page-break is not hyphenated. Can this be reported automatically by some Lua magic? How?

Or even better, could Lua put the hyphenated word into `\hbox` and reflow the paragraph -- hoping it will break in the same place, with that word just moved forth or back a bit?

Comment: It won't cause a paragraph to be broken differently into lines, but Knuth's TeX engine already has `\brokenpenalty` to tell how much you are reluctant to see a page break right after a line ending at a discretionary break (see the last paragraph of the TeXbook p. 104).

Comment: @frougon I know about that; that's the old-style bottom-up information flow, without feedback from page-break back into line-break. For continuous text on small paper (like in my case), it would mean changing the number of lines per page, which is not desirable.

Comment: Correct, that's why I didn't write this as an answer. I just wanted to make sure you knew about the knob. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting a hyphenated word into a `\hbox`, which would require actually determining where a word begins and ends, there is another way: Whenever a page is broken at a discretionary (the TeX node which represents e.g. a hyphen), reflow the paragraph with one additional restraint: Do not break at this point. That's easy, because Lua code can change the penalty associated with a linebreak at a discretionary node. Of course, after reflowing the text, the new breakpoint might still be a discretionary. Then we just repeat the procedure until we are happy with the break.

This hasn't been tested with lots of documents, so it might break in more complicated situations.

The code (Some explenations in the comments):
(Replace `\includecomment` by `\excludecomment` to disable the code and see the "normal" linebreaking in effect.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext,luacode}
\usepackage{comment}
% \excludecomment{nobroken}
\includecomment{nobroken}
\begin{nobroken}
\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
  local discardable_id = {
    [node.id'glue'] = true,
    [node.id'kern'] = true,
    [node.id'penalty'] = true,
  }
  -- A small helper to use properties. They are used to store the paragraphs without linebreaks.
  local function swap_prop(n, new) -- If new is `false`, it is not changed. Use `nil` to clear the prop
    local p = node.getproperty(n)
    if not p then
      p = {}
      node.setproperty(n, p)
    end
    local prop = p.nohyphout
    p.nohyphout = new == false and prop or new
    return prop
  end
  -- Actually save the paragraphs
  local function pre(n, ctxt)
    if ctxt ~= "" or n.id ~= 9 then return true end -- Nothing to see here, but at least unlikely
    local discretionaries, m = {}, node.copy_list(n)
    swap_prop(n, {unbroken = m, discretionaries = discretionaries})
    while n do -- We have to save the correspondance between the original and the copied nodes
      if n.id == 7 then -- For performance reasons, we only save the discretionaries. We never change other nodes anyway
      discretionaries[node.direct.todirect(n)] = m
      end
      m, n = m.next, n.next
    end
    return true
  end
  -- After linebreaking, we save the node of the last line. This allows deleting "wrong" versions later on.
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", pre, "save unbroken") -- Of course, saving the unbroken paragraph only works before linebreaking
  local post = function(n, ctxt)
    if ctxt ~= "" then return true end
    while n and n.id ~= 0 do n = n.next end -- There often comes glue/penalties/other stuff in front of the first actual line
    local head = n.head
    if not head or head.id ~= 9 then return true end -- Nothing to see here, but at least unlikely
    local prop = swap_prop(head, false)
    if prop and prop.unbroken then
      prop.parend = node.tail(n)
    end
    return true
  end
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter", post, "save parend")

  -- The important functionality: We define a macro \adjustbreaks, which looks at the output box. If the end does not end with hyphen, the first TeX parameter is executed, otherwise a new attempt is made and the second parameter is executed.
  local luafunc = luatexbase.new_luafunction"adjustbreaks"
  token.set_lua("adjustbreaks", luafunc, "global", "protected")
  lua.get_functions_table()[luafunc] = function()
    local list = tex.box[255]
    local last, lastline
    for hlist in node.traverse(list.head) do
      if hlist.id == 0 and hlist.head and hlist.head.id == 9 then
        if last and last.unbroken then
          node.flush_list(last.unbroken)
          last = nil
        end
        local new = swap_prop(hlist.head, nil)
        if new and new.unbroken then
          last, new.parbegin = new, hlist
        end
      end
      if hlist.id == 0 and last then
        if last.parend == hlist then
          node.flush_list(last.unbroken)
          last = nil
        end
        lastline = hlist
      end
    end
    if last then -- We reached the end of a page and it ends with a broken paragraph which we *could* change.
      local lastnondiscard
      for n in node.traverse(lastline.head) do
        if not discardable_id[n.id] then
          lastnondiscard = n
        end
      end
      if lastnondiscard and lastnondiscard.id == 7 then -- We end with a discretionary. Let's change that!
        -- This is the interesting part:
        -- We probably never reach this point if the paragraph isn't fully "contributed" to the outer vlist,
        -- so last.parend is in the list starting at tex.lists.contrib_head
        -- We want to remove the already broken paragraph, so reset the head to the node *after* our last line.
        do
          local curr, afterpar = tex.lists.contrib_head, last.parend.next
          while curr ~= afterpar do curr = node.free(curr) end
          tex.lists.contrib_head = curr
        end
        -- Also forbid the current linebreak, otherwise this wouldn't do anything
        last.discretionaries[node.direct.todirect(lastnondiscard)].penalty = 10000
        -- We might need multiple passes and after linebreaking the `unbroken` list will no longer be unbroken,
        -- So we run our callbacks again to fix everything up. Then run the linebreaking system again.
        -- We should probaby set tome parameters, but to get them we have to add a `linebreak_filter` callback.
        -- Currently I want to avoid that. FIXME!
        pre(last.unbroken, "")
        local broken = tex.linebreak(last.unbroken) -- TODO: Get params
        post(broken, "")
        -- Now broken starts probably with some penalties or glue.
        -- But we never deleted the glue in front of our paragraph, so adding it again would double it.
        -- Instead just skip it:
        while broken and broken.id ~= 0 do broken = node.free(broken) end
        last.parbegin.prev.next = broken
        node.flush_list(last.parbegin)
        token.put_next(token.create'@secondoftwo')
        return
      else
        node.flush_list(last.unbroken)
        last = nil
      end
    end
    token.put_next(token.create'@firstoftwo')
  end
```

```
\end{luacode*}
% Now we still have to change the output routine to actually use \adjustbreaks
% First save the old one
\let\myrealoutput\output
\newtoks\output
\output\expandafter{\the\myrealoutput}
% Now set the new output routine. If \adjustbreaks does not find any problems with the current page, just continue with the regular output routine.
% Otherwise put \outputbox back into the page, then TeX tries again to find a pagebreak.
\myrealoutput{\adjustbreaks{\the\output}{\unvbox255}}
\end{nobroken}
\begin{document}
\hyphenpenalty0 -- This is only for testing, you normally do NOT want \hyphenpenalty0 in actual documents.
\blindtext[5]
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Jackdaws love my big Sphinx of Quartz.
Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.
The five boxing wizards jump quickly.
Sympathizing would fix Quaker objectives.
Many-wived Jack laughs at probes of sex quiz.
% Turgid saxophones blew over Mick’s jazzy quaff.
% Playing jazz vibe chords quickly excites my wife.
% A large fawn jumped quickly over white zinc boxes.
% Exquisite farm wench gives body jolt to prize stinker.
According to a list of long words on grammerly.com, one of the best known long words in the english language is a word which the Oxforddictionary describes as ``a nonsense word''. Therefore it fits perfectly into this supercalifragilisticexpialidocious text.
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is not a good idea to test the `node.id` numbers directly, as the numbers aren't stable. I've learned this hard way when LuaTeX 1.0 was released. It is better to save the tested ids to variables, like `local glue_id = node.id "glue"`

Comment: btw, this code could be useful as a package on CTAN :)